# SQL Server Import Export wizard - error for datetime - specific values

Tags: sql-server-2008, import, ssis, wizard

I am using SQL Server 2008 Import Export wizard to bulk import a text file.

The text file contains more than 9 Lakh records with column delimiter `|` and row delimiter / terminator as `{LF}`

Everything is working fine, except in one case: there is one column in the table with datatype `datetime` and there are few records in text file having dates like `01/07/1861`, `09/08/1865` etc. and the wizard fails to import these type of records giving error "Invalid Date Format"

Can any one assist me?

Thanks and Regards,
Pratik

UPDATE -

The problem is with only date value `08/08/1696`.

Even if I try to run simple query like following:

select convert(datetime,'08/08/1696', 101) it gives error like “The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.”

Comment: [Lakh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) = 100,000 for people like me who were ignorant

Comment: What data type is that column defined as in the Flat File Connection Manager? DT_DBDATE, DT_DBTIMESTAMP, DT_DBTIMESTAMP2, etc. My guess at this moment is that isn't a valid range for the SSIS datetime type you selected but I'll need to look up the type mappings once I get to work.

Comment: it is mapped to DT_DBTIMESTAMP

Comment: And what is the destination column defined as? datetime, datetime2, date?

Comment: It's a hard thing, because your process should work with your settings. I tried to reproduce the problem, but I couldn't. As billinkc suggested, if all your date is greater than 01/01/1753, no error should happen.

Comment: others are also facing such a problem (http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/507838/invalid-date-format-ssis-sql-provider)

Comment: Exactly there is the problem, as billinkc suggested. '08/08/1696' does not fall within the expected range of the datetime SQL type. The date must be between '01/01/1753' and '31/12/9999' (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) Use datetime2 instead which is valid from '01/01/0001'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best thing to do is to import everything to a staging table with all column data types as NVARCHAR or VARCHAR.

Once this is done you can then convert the data easily from string to date.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/47fc07d2-37fe-4dd8-b57f-3867cd57e2b0

Comment: Great answer mate.  Might have been sat next to you when you answered it :) Hope your doing well

Answer (score 0):

I would only suggest to check the actual format of your data in the source database. In my case I solved the issue by passing nullable datetime2 to date fiels. This worked because the wizard was not reading correctly the source database and it was passing this wrong format (the source database was using datetime2, and the wizard was passing smalldatetime, creating the error).